# How to add another text feature to current bag of words classification? In Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification

this is my input matrix [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdtfx.png)

my sample Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['Extract'], 
data['Expense Account code Description'], random_state = 0)

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline , FeatureUnion
text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))),
              ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf = False)),
              ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =100, 
 max_features='log2',criterion = 'entropy')),
 ])
 text_clf = text_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

here I am applying Bag of word model for 'Extract' column classifying 'Expense Account code Description' , Here i am getting an accuracy of around 92% , but if i want to include 'Vendor name' as the set of another input feature how can i do that.  Is there any way of doing it along with the bag of words ? ,

Comment: You can use [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to combine the features. But first you must convert the vendor names to numerical, (encoding categorical to numerical form).

Comment: for Converting vendor names , can i use the same Bag of words model ? Then i use featureUnion to combine the features. I am new to this , i may sound silly.

Comment: Vendor names are not like general text. So I dont think Bag of words will behave any different than simple one-hot encoding. Try one-hot encoding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FeatureUnion.
also you will need to create a new Transformer class with the necessary actions you need to take i.e. Include Vendor name , get dummies.

Feature Union will fit in your pipeline.

For reference.

```
class get_Vendor(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def transform(self, X,y):
        return 

lr_tfidf = Pipeline([('features',FeatureUnion([('other',get_vendor()),
        ('vect', tfidf)])),('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])
```